# Sweet Alert with laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, sweetalert

I am trying to have a simple pop up using Sweet Alert, basically I want to be able to check if the user has any previous violations in his record.. I have made a controller method which checks that and in my view I am using Ajax to fire the method..
I am using realrashid sweet alert JS library
here is my view:

```html
@include('sweetalert::alert')

<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
<div class="form-group">
<strong>Customer ID:</strong>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="custidno" id='cust' required autocomplete="off" onkeypress="myFunction()"  placeholder="Customer ID" >
<button onclick="CheckViolation()"class="btn-info"type="button">Check for Violation</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Script

```js
function CheckViolation()
      {
        var customerid= document.getElementById("cust").value;
        var url = "{{ url('violationcheck') }}";
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", url + "?" +"custidno=" + customerid, true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
```

and the controller method:

```php
        public function violationcheck(Request $request)
    {
      $custidno = customer::select("id")
      ->where('name',$request->custidno)
      ->first();
      $checked = DB::table('violations')
      ->select('severity',DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
      ->where("customer_id",$custidno->id)
      ->where("status",1)
      ->groupBy('severity')
      ->first();
      if(empty($checked))
      {
        Alert::info('Info Message', 'No Violation found');


      }else{
          $msg="Violation found";
          Alert::info('Info Message', 'Violation found');


            }
            return view('assignees.create');
      }
```

when pressing" Check for violation, nothing happens, upon looking at the page, it is being loaded into browser but pop up is not appearing...

Comment: Some sensible code-formatting and indenting would make your code much easier to read.

Comment: Did you included the sweetalert .js and .css in your view? https://github.com/uxweb/sweet-alert#the-view

Answer (score 0):

it won't work because you are using ajax and Alert is using session to show sweetalert dialog